# Can JUNG library make edges based on predefined properties?

Tags: java, graph, jung

I have some data of let’s say type Person. This Person has a phone-number property but also a calling and a called phone-number properties.

```
class Person {
   String id;
   String displayName;
   String phoneNr;
   String callingNr; // or List<String> callingNrs;
   String calledNr;  // or List<String> calledNrs;
}
```

What I want, is I put a bunch of those Person objects in a Graph instance and than render the relationships on a view. Ideally the components drawn on the view are interactive, meaning you can click on a node/vertex that highlight the edges (and maybe more).

I tried JUNG, but in the documentation, I see some examples that I have to, kind of, define the relationships between Person objects myself, like below:

```
Graph.addEdge("edge-name", personA.phoneNr, personB.phoneNr);
```

I’m new to JUNG, but maybe there’s a way to tell JUNG about the properties of Person and that JUNG knows how to connect them?

Is this possible with JUNG? Or do I need another type of library, if yes, than can someone please provide me one I can use?

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I would do:

Make a java.util.Map of each person's phone number (key) to an instance of the Person (value). That is your reverse number lookup.
Populate your reverse number lookup map by iterating over your collection of people using the PhoneNr as the key and the Person instance as the value.

Next, I would create an edge class 'PhoneCall' that contains information like 'time of call' and 'duration of call' (more or less info, depending on what you have available).

To add edges to your graph, iterate over your collection of Person instances, and for each Person, iterate over the collection of calling numbers. For each calling number, use the reverse number lookup map to get the person calling and make a directed edge to connect the calling person to the current person.
Do something similar for the each Person's collection of called numbers.
Your graph nodes will be Person instances, and your edges will be PhoneCall instances that connect one Person to another. Be sure to add an equals and hashCode method to your Person class and to your PhoneCall class so that they will work properly (and duplicates will be detected and hopefully ignored).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thnx! Do you know of an example I can use. I really like to use examples for better understanding. Thnx anyway.